# Search in HTML document with Python and lxml upwards

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have a HTML document with a structure like this:

```
<html>
  <li>
     <a href="" />a1</a>
     <other tags ... />
     <li>
        <a href="">a2</a>
        <another one tag ... />
        <a name=3>
     </li>
  </li>
  <li>
    ...
  </li>
```

I need to find all parent **a** elements, located undert **li** elements and build a path for **a** element with **name=3**. In this example it should be *a1/a2*. I use lxml and wrote this Python code:

```
import lxml
...

def get_path_for_series(self, html, series):
    current = html.xpath('//a[@name="%s"]' % series)[0]
    path = list()
    while True:
        category = current.xpath('.//ancestor::li[1]//a[1]')
        if len(category) == 0:
            break
        path.append(self.clear(category[0].text_content()))
        current = category[0]
    return '/'.join(path)
```

It finds the first element correctly, but then I hav an infinate loop. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop starts by traversing to ancestor `li` and get the descendant `a[1]`. Then from current `a`, in the next loop your XPath will traverse to the same `li` ancestor again and return the same `a` element, and this goes on forever (add `print current` to verify. I saw `Element` at the same memory location, meaning they are the same instance, get printed over and over).

You can try to move up the tree statring from the target `a[@name="%s"]` instead, and join the collected path steps in reverse like so :

```
def get_path_for_series(self, html, series):
    current = html.xpath('//a[@name="%s"]' % series)[0]
    path = list()
    parent = current.xpath('parent::li')

    while parent:
        a = parent[0].xpath('a[1]')[0]
        path.append(a.text)
        parent = parent[0].xpath('parent::li')

    # join `path` in reversed order
    return '/'.join(path[::-1])
```